# Working through a filtered set in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, filter, traversal

I am a newbie to VBA.  I have found part of my solution, but all the examples I have seen fall short of what I need.

I have up and down buttons in a VBA form, which need to show data from a filtered set.  I have worked out that I can apply a filter using this code:

```
Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A3:AM" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

and this works well.

Now what I need is to go up and down that data depending on whether the up or down button was pressed, and then get the data from the corresponding row and column.

I know that I can use a `For` loop similar to the following:

```
For Each Row In Range("A1", Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
   GWEPId = Cells(Row.Row, 1)
   Grip5Status = Cells(Row.Row, 4)
Next Row
```

but I don't know how to do this using the first method.

If I press down, I want to go to the next filtered row, and if I press up, I want to go back to the previous filtered row.

Do I need to put all the data in an array and then go up and down from the array? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50583166/edit) to include more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if I actually understand your question fully, but here is my attempt with the following assumptions:

- You have an actual filter applied on the first row
- You have selected an actual row in your database

Then here is a piece of code that will get you the values from a higher row

```
Sub GetDataMinus()
'Assign code to your button to get values one row higher

Dim FR As Long, LR As Long, X As Long

FR = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Row
LR = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If ActiveCell.Row > FR Then
    For X = ActiveCell.Row - 1 To FR Step -1
        If Not Cells(X, 1).Rows.Hidden Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(X).Select
            Debug.Print Cells(X, 1).Value 'Link the value to where you want to store it, e.g. on your userform
            Debug.Print Cells(X, 4).Value 'Link the value to where you want to store it, e.g. on your userform
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next X
End If

End Sub
```

And here is a piece of code that will get you the values a row lower:

```
Sub GetDataPlus()
'Assign code to your button to get values one row lower

Dim FR As Long, LR As Long, X As Long

FR = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 1).Row
LR = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If ActiveCell.Row < LR Then
    For X = ActiveCell.Row + 1 To LR
        If Not Cells(X, 1).Rows.Hidden Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(X).Select
            Debug.Print Cells(X, 1).Value 'Link the value to where you want to store it, e.g. on your userform
            Debug.Print Cells(X, 4).Value 'Link the value to where you want to store it, e.g. on your userform
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next X
End If

End Sub
```

I want to make a few notes:

- The code can be made more elegant, there is (long) way to extract the last visible row in a filtered range. I just didn't apply it here as I feel it doesn't add that much.
- I didn't test this code on a userform but I'm sure you will be able to make the adjustments where needed.
- In the code I assume you selected a row in the database. However you could also store the last used row on your userform and use that as an input. Idea?
- More ways to Rome, so there might be actual better ways doing this, however this was my attempt :)

Good luck with it.

Comment: Hey, thanks very much for this!  I copy pasted the code and it works almost perfectly!  the only things I have to do is switch the down/up as it seems reversed.  This has saved me a lot of time messing with global variables etc.   Thanks again.